# How does Sanji produce fire in Water?

Tags: one-piece

As you know, Sanji has a move called Diable Jamble, where he somehow manages to generate fire on his leg by rotating with great speed.

We have seen this move first when he was fighting CP9.

According to science, fire can be generated by friction, but it should be spontaneous. This explains as to how he was able to generate while he was fighting CP9 at Enies Lobby.

But after the timeskip, when the Straw Hat Pirates were on their way to Fishman Island, they encountered a Kraken. How did Sanji generate fire in water?

In water, there is no rough material via which, fire can be generated.

And even if it is somehow achieved, how can the fire not get extinguished by the water!?

[image: Sanji using his move in water!]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As usual, Oda Eiichiro has a "creative" explanation for that too! Oda blatantly disobeys the Laws of our world in One Piece.

In SBS Volume 44, when asked how Sanji could beat Jabra by heating his leg, without burning it, Oda's response was:

> Sanji's leg is not hot!! His heart was burning so much hotter!!

If asked your question, he would *probably* say something like:

> Learning Haki, spending 2 years chased by Okamas, and being separated from ladies, especially Nami-san and Robin-chan, has made his heart burn much hotter!!! Even water cannot extinguish his burning heart!!!

I know, it doesn't feel satisfying, but this is how Oda-sensei's "explanations" usually are!

Comment: It's no use trying to think of the OP world in terms of our world. Remember Pappagu, who learned to talk because he *thought* he was a human, and it was too late, when he realised he was not! Even *Luffy* questioned how that could work!

Comment: Also, we could just blame it on the Haki. :P Luffy's haki makes his body becomes *black*. We've seen Vergo turn purplish when he uses haki. So may be, Sanji's burning heart and his haki, takes this form.

Comment: @R.J As for Luffy's Haki, there's a more "acceptable" reason for the black color. Read my answer here: http://anime.stackexchange.com/a/5717/99. I don't agree with the accepted answer there.

Comment: Totally agree with you Happy. Just that, I'm saying that it might be a case, where Sanji's leg turns that color when he uses Haki. It's just a speculation, based on the other Haki colors! :)

Comment: Yes, that is totally possible. Oda's imagination knows no bounds, no telling what he might be thinking. :)

Comment: Oda's imagination has no bounds, because the information available on this planet has no bounds. He is known to pick up so many things, from names to personalities, from so many various sources, that many things in One Piece world are mere speculations(unless he reveals them).

Comment: Im kind of getting what your trying to say. But the haki which is shown is normally for defence, perception and conquerers. So this cannot possibly be haki in the form of fire!
The heat in his heart could heat up sanji, but using that heat he burns his opponent, that is weird O_o

Comment: @MärmîkŠhâh - Welcome to Oda's world of *One Piece*, where you can always expected the totally unexpected things! :)

Comment: haha Oda never fails to surprise me!

Comment: He is the creator of Luffy after all. What else can you expect? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel like Sanji uses Haki to incinerate his leg just like Luffy used Haki to use the Red Hawk attack. If you remember Luffy's fight vs Hordy, Luffy uses the Red Hawk attack (which uses Armorment Haki to make his arms catch on fire) under water. Maybe Sanji uses that on his leg to attack. Just a theory.

Comment: Any source to proof this? if not I don't think this really answers the question

Answer (score 0):

As we all know, Sanji has acquired Haki and Sky Walk. If Sky Walk (also Blue Walk, but underwater) can serve as a foundation for friction, and Haki as an incinerator, then we get fire underwater. We know that Luffy can generate fire thanks to this logic... Haki and speed.

Answer (score -1):

This is my own theory but his flames could be from the power he was supposed to get at birth. All his siblings had powers but he was considered a dud. If I am wrong he could get powers later on or he might never get them.

Just realized no one has commented in over a year and you guys didn't have this info, that I am basing my theory off of, when it was originally posted.